# How to use comparator with multiple conditions while handling the null pointer exception

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, comparator

I am not to using lambdas and I am finding it very hard to stream and change value for a attribute called status based on some conditions.

testList has a list of elements of type Testdto.

```java
MasterDto {
    List<TestDto> testListContent;
}
    
TestDto {
    Long id;
    @NotNull
    LocalDate startDate; /// This is not nullable
    LocalDate endDate; // This is nullable. Hence we have to handle null pointer exceptions.
    String status;
}
```

Initially all the status values are either `"Inactive"` or `"Future"` or `"Expired"`.

I want to change value of ONE object's status to `"ACTIVE"` whose status is currently `"Inactive"` and whose effective date is most recent.

If there are more than one objects whose effective dates are most recent and equal, we have to choose the object whose enddate value is higher. (`Endate` is nullable, so we have to avoid nullpointer exception here)

If enddates of those objects are also similar OR NULL, we can choose the first one in the list.

Here is what I came up with so far

```java
masterDtos.gettestListContent()
    .stream()
.max(Comparator.comparing(TestDto::getStartDate)
.thenComparing(
    Comparator.nullsLast(
    Comparator.nullsLast(TestDto::getEndDate)
.get().setStatus(ACTIVE_STATUS);
```

Comment: Please provide an example, input and expected output, thanks.

Comment: Note that using `get()` without a check for presence is dangerous and will fail if no argument exists. Use `ifPresent(do-> dto.setStatus(ACTIVE_STATUS))`.

Answer (score 0):

You’re close.  You should be calling nullLast only once.  Note that [nullsLast takes another Comparator as argument](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast(java.util.Comparator)), namely the Comparator to invoke if and only if both values being compared are not null.

```
masterDtos.gettestListContent()                                 // correct
    .stream()                                                   // correct
    .max(                                                       // correct
        Comparator.comparing(TestDto::getStartDate)             // correct
        .thenComparing(                                         // correct
            TestDto::getEndDate,                                // compare using...
            Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())     // ...null-safe comparator
        )
    )
.get().setStatus(ACTIVE_STATUS);
```

Comment: But the end date check should happen only if two effective dates are recent and equal. otherwise, we should not be checking end dates. Where are we doing that ?

Comment: @AlexRudenko Right you are.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several points to address in the original code:

1. [`Comparator::nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) is applied to another comparator such as `Comparator.naturalOrder`, not to the method reference.
2. One should use `Optional::ifPresent` to modify the state of the relevant item in the list if found.

Thus, the code should look as follows:

```java
public static void activateLastInactive(List<TestDto> data) {
    data.stream()
        .filter(t -> "Inactive".equalsIgnoreCase(t.status))
        .max(
                Comparator.comparing(TestDto::getStartDate)
                          .thenComparing(TestDto::getEndDate, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
        )
        .ifPresent(t -> t.setStatus("Active"));
    System.out.println("After: " + data);
}
```

Tests

```java
List<TestDto> data = Arrays.asList(
        new TestDto(1L, LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 1), null, "Active"),
        new TestDto(2L, LocalDate.of(2021, 8, 8), LocalDate.of(2021, 9, 1), "Inactive"),
        new TestDto(3L, LocalDate.of(2021, 8, 8), null, "Inactive"),
        new TestDto(4L, LocalDate.of(2021, 8, 8), null, "Inactive")
) ;

System.out.println("Before: " + data);
activateLastInactive(data);

activateLastInactive(data);

activateLastInactive(data);
```

Output

```
Before: [TestDto(id=1, startDate=2021-01-01, endDate=null, status=Active), TestDto(id=2, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=2021-09-01, status=Inactive), TestDto(id=3, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=null, status=Inactive), TestDto(id=4, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=null, status=Inactive)]

After: [TestDto(id=1, startDate=2021-01-01, endDate=null, status=Active), TestDto(id=2, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=2021-09-01, status=Inactive), TestDto(id=3, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=null, status=Active), TestDto(id=4, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=null, status=Inactive)]
// id 3 activated

After: [TestDto(id=1, startDate=2021-01-01, endDate=null, status=Active), TestDto(id=2, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=2021-09-01, status=Inactive), TestDto(id=3, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=null, status=Active), TestDto(id=4, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=null, status=Active)]
// id 4 activated

After: [TestDto(id=1, startDate=2021-01-01, endDate=null, status=Active), TestDto(id=2, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=2021-09-01, status=Active), TestDto(id=3, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=null, status=Active), TestDto(id=4, startDate=2021-08-08, endDate=null, status=Active)]
// id 2 activated
```